# Huawei P30 Pro locked out with "Android System: User Data Locked" error

Tags: huawei, locked-out, system-error, airplane-mode

Just checking if anyone faced an issue with "Android System: User Data Locked" on Huawei P30 Pro.

My Huawei P30 Pro got locked after a middle-of-the-night auto-update. I keyed in the usual password the next morning but the login failed. I tried all different passwords and it still doesn't work. To make matters worse and for whatever reasons, the phone went into airplane mode after a few restarts of the phone.

I cannot afford a factory reset as it contains all her work and personal stuff. We went to Huawei Service Centre and they are unable to help as well.

Any way to force kick the phone out of airplane mode?

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. There are a few suggestions on [a big Google's Android Help thread](https://support.google.com/android/thread/37077878/android-system-user-data-locked-on-my-father-s-huawei-mate-20-he-cannot-access-his-phone-anymore), ranging from inputting the Google Account's password, restarting, shutting down and waiting for a few hours, and lastly inputting the last password set up on an app. Unfortunately, I'm not sure if airplane mode can be toggled from the notification drawer while locked or not.

Comment: Also posted on XDA Forums, just in case it's answered there: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/user-data-locked.4601705/

Answer (score 0):

You have probably tried this, but have not indicated it in your question.

---

**Clear Cache Partition**  from [Guide on how to wipe cache partition of Huawei P30 or P30 Pro:](https://itechify.com/2019/10/26/how-to-wipe-cache-partition-of-huawei-p30-pro/)

> 1. First of all, turn off the phone using the “Power button”.
> 2. Now press and hold the power button and volume up button.
> 3. Keep on pressing the buttons till you see “Huawei” written on the screen.
> 4. Now, you will be in recovery mode. You will see a number of options.
> 5. Use the volume button to navigate to “Wipe Cache Partition” and use the power button to make the selection.
> 6. Wait for the phone to format the cache partition. Once it is done you will see it on the screen. Do not reset while the cache partition is being cleared. Otherwise, it can brick your phone.
> 7. Once you are done with clearing cache partition of Huawei P30. Use the volume button to navigate to the “Reboot System Now” option. Use the Power button to make the selection.

---

**Safe Mode** From [HOW TO ENTER SAFE MODE ON HUAWEI P30 PRO](HOW TO ENTER SAFE MODE ON HUAWEI P30 PRO)

> - Turn off the device.
> - Press and hold Power button.
> - Tap Restart.
> - When the device is restarting, press the Volume Down and Power buttons simultaneously.
> - When the device logo appears, release the Power button and continue to press the Volume Down.
> - If you see Safe Mode in the lower-left corner after the device restart, Safe Mode is on, otherwise you need to repeat the process.

If you can get into safe mode then one of your apps is the problem.  You can try deleting them, starting with ones that don't have of your data.

Comment: Sorry, can I go into safe mode thru the EMUI menu?

Comment: I can go into safe mode but I can't login. Still prompt me for the password.